# NET MAUI doesn't show option to compile with android

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I usually build apps with Xamarin, and today I decided to test MAUI, but I don't see the option to compile with Android.

I already ran the command "dotnet workload restore", and I get the message that it is already installed.

Does anyone know what can it be?
Thanks

Comment: please do NOT post errors as images

Comment: sorry, I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the command `dotnet workload repair`.